# TypeError: knex.raw is not a function

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I am using postgres to store an array of data with the help of knex to update data with the following code:

```
app.put('/groceryList', (req, res) => {
    const { id, listUpdated } = req.body;
    db('users')
    .where('id', '=', id)
    .update({
        grocerylist: knex.raw('array_append(grocerylist, ?)', listUpdated)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error returning grocery list'))
})
```

...why am I receiving a "TypeError: knex.raw is not a function"?

Comment: how would we know? you haven't even included your declaration of `knex`

Comment: its been declared

Comment: CollinD you cant look at what ive provided and give me a clue of where I may be going wrong? And if not give an example of why not?

Comment: You use `db` to reference the table, are you importing/declaring your `knex` object as `db`? (aka should that read `db.raw`)? Else, it would be helpful if you provided the line where `knex` is declared.

Comment: yes I am declaring knex through db...let me see if the db.raw works. im sure it will, rookie mistake. thank you, phasma

Comment: it worked! pure genius, phasma! thank you :)

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project!